# "50400: Gateway Timeout." in BizTalk services for large XML files

Tags: azure, biztalk, servicebus

"50400: Gateway Timeout." in BizTalk services for large XML files

Comment: Some more details? e.g.  Incoming or outgoing?  Filesize?  Protocol? Configurations you've tried?

Comment: Looks like your gateway gave a timeout. You might want to look into that .. by the way: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/57ec0fda-ad23-4790-ad71-57dcfa18476b/service-bus-relay-timeout-when-executing-a-long-operation-50400-gateway-timeout?forum=servbus

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ  Yes, I saw that post as well.  Was no answer to it except from the OP though with a further question.

Comment: I'm using FTP as source and SQL server as destination. Reading from FTP is successful, when import into sql database after inserting around 3000 records it gives gateway timeout issue. When file size is greater than 4 mb it gives above error. protocol is http only.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule BizTalk is not SSIS, BizTalk is not an ETL (Extract, Transform and Load), BizTalk is not meant to insert thousand and thousand of rows at one time.

Try to chunk your file in little part and process say 10 at a time. (BatchSize=10)

If you really can't do this and want continue with this solution increase your send timeout property available in WCF-CUSTOM or WCF-SQL adapter Configuration.